# How can I fix java.io.FileNotFoundException in java?

Tags: java

how can I fix this problem :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: EtatServ-85101-23032019.xls (Le processus ne peut pas accéder au fichier car ce fichier est utilisé par un autre processus)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknenter code hereown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.soprabanking.printout.TestUtil.forceDesignCreator(TestUtil.java:39)
    at com.soprabanking.printout.ApplicatoinTest.main(ApplicatoinTest.java:122)
```

Comment: Check that the file isn't locked by another process (e.g by Excel) .

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the relevant code to check where the error is from. Also, what is your analysis? You cannot just throw a problem and leave like this... Also, (lucky I am French reader), the error is quite clear: you want to open a file, I assume this file exists, which is locked by another process.

Comment: I just changed the title sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Close this excel file: `EtatServ-85101-23032019.xls`